# Running Testcafe in Docker Containers in Kubernetes - 1337 Port is Already in Use - Error

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, port, testcafe

I have multiple Testcafe scripts (`script1.js`, `script2.js`) that are working fine. I have Dockerized this code into a Dockerfile and it works fine when I run the Docker Image. Next, I want to invoke this Docker Image as a CronJob in Kubernetes. Given below is my `manifest.yaml` file.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: application-automation-framework
  namespace: development
  labels:
    team: development
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      labels:
        team: development
    spec:
      ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 120
      backoffLimit: 3
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            team: development
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: script1-job
              image: testcafe-minikube
              imagePullPolicy: Never
              args: ["chromium:headless", "script1.js"]
            - name: script2-job
              image: testcafe-minikube
              imagePullPolicy: Never
              args: [ "chromium:headless", "script2.js"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

As seen above, this manifest has two containers running. When I apply this manifest to Kubernetes, the first container (`script1-job`), runs well. But the second container (`script2-job`) gives me the following error.

```
ERROR The specified 1337 port is already in use by another program.
```

If I run this with one container, it works perfectly. I also tried changing the args of the containers to the following.

```
args: ["chromium:headless", "script1.js", "--ports 12345,12346"]
args: ["chromium:headless", "script2.js", "--ports 1234,1235"]
```

Still, I get the same error saying 1337 port already in use. (I wonder whether the `--ports` argument is working at all in Docker).

This is my `Dockerfile` for reference.

```
FROM testcafe/testcafe
COPY . ./
USER root
RUN npm install
```

Could someone please help me with this? I want to run multiple containers as Cronjobs in Kubernetes, where I can run multiple Testcafe scripts in each job invocation?

Answer (score 3):

adding the containerPort configuration to your kubernetes resource should do the trick.

for example:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: script1-job
          image: testcafe-minikube
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          args: ["chromium:headless", "script1.js", "--ports 12345,12346"]
          ports: 
          - containerPort: 12346
```